# In setup.py, how to test if PyCapsule_New is defined?

Tags: python, distutils

`setup.py` has a feature for testing if functions are defined:

```
compiler = distutils.ccompiler.new_compiler ()
if compiler.has_function ('foo_new', libraries=("foo",)):
    define_macros.append (('HAVE_FOO_NEW', '1'))
```

However I can't seem to use this for Python extension functions (specifically `PyCapsule_New`).  The following does not define anything:

```
if compiler.has_function ('PyCapsule_New'):
    define_macros.append (('HAVE_PYCAPSULE_NEW', '1'))
```

I seem to need to put something in the `libraries` argument, but what?  The name of the Python library changes, and is not available in `distutils.sysconfig` except as a gcc parameter (eg. `BLDLIBRARY` is defined as something like `-L. -lpython2.7`).

It seems like such an obvious/common thing to want to do so the code will work on multiple versions of Python, but no `setup.py` scripts I can find use `has_function` in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing configure checks for Python features, you could do some compile-time testing. Ideally you could check against the Python version (`PY_MAJOR_VERSION`, `PY_MINOR_VERSION`), but you could also rely on macros defined inside the headers.

For your specific feature, note that the `Py_CAPSULE_H` macro is defined once the header `pycapsule.h` is included (via `Python.h`).